# Some problem in search specific value in specific key

Tags: python

I wants to search specific value in specific key.
example:

```
x = [12, {"hello":"world",}]
if x["hello"] == "world":
   print "Found!"
```

My example above is wrong.
What to do?

Answer (score 2):

> My example above is wrong. What to do?

Correct it, maybe? Honestly, I feel compelled to link to this:
[How to ask questions the smart way?](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

That being said, the problem is you are trying to index a list with a string, which is not possible. Either do

```
x[1]["hello"] == "world"
```

...or simply get rid of the list, there isn't really a reason to use it, anyway. If you want to store additional data, you might as well use the dictionary for that.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing dictionaries and lists. You probably don't really know how they work.

Lists may have any object you want and are accessed by their position:

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> x[2]
'c'
```

Dicts combine hashable objects (non mutable) as keys with values that can be anything. You access a object by it's key (and they aren't kept ordered).

```
>>> y = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
>>> y['c']
>>> 2
```